# How can the production jar specify its own dependencies when added to other project as a dependency?

Tags: maven, netbeans, maven-2, maven-3

If the question title can't make it clear, take me explain here in more detail. Suppose the production jar of one of my Maven applications needs to be used into my other Maven web-application. Adding that jar to my second application Maven dependency doesn't add its transitive dependencies. Also, the jar in itself is an application.

One way is to look at the POM of the first application and add those in the POM of the other application. But then, how do central Maven jars add their own transitive dependencies when added to some project.

In other words, if I add `commons-io.jar` Maven dependency to my project, it automatically adds its transitive dependencies. But when I add `myjar.jar` as a Maven dependency (scope->system) then it doesn't automatically adds its transitive dependencies.

I think that I should develop my first application as some other archetype which can be used in such a case. Please advise me how to proceed further.

Sorry for this newbie question. Actually, I'm new to Maven and I've started using Netbeans-embedded-maven to create applications. I really like the way Maven simplifies the job.

`edited`

Seems like I should explain in more detail. So here is it.

Suppose I wrote a program/application that used A.jar,B.jar,C.jar and my production output was X.jar (which obviously doesn't contain other jars within as per maven default build). The above A,B,C jars are present in maven central repository and were added as dependency to my project. The project build jar is X.jar

Now I write another application in which I added X.jar as a system dependency, now what I want is that A.jar, B.jar, C.jar added automatically to the project since they are transitive dependencies for X.jar

Hope so I've explained it clear this time. Please forgive me for my writing style in case you didn't understand earlier.

One solution is to build X.jar containing all dependencies within it using something like this

```
 <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>com.nitinsurana.mlmmaven.Start</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-my-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

But I'm looking for something that automatically adds transitive dependencies of a system dependency.

Comment: Try to use compile scope.

Comment: @madhead ? compile is the default scope

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd yes. But I think he specified system scope explicitly.

Comment: @madhead compile scope is not letting me have <systemPath> tag to specify it's location.

Comment: @XCoder to use compile scope, you need to install jar to one of your repos (local would be ok). I am not sure, but maven may not manage transitive dependencies for system-scoped jars (as they may not have pom).

Comment: @madhead thanks for the reply. I was having the same doubt. I'll install the jar locally and put it under compile scope. But I'm quite sure the PRODUCTION jar doesn't have a POM. So I still guess i'll still be stuck. Please let me know how to build the production jar in such a manner that it contains POM, so that the jar can be used as an application and also as a maven dependency.

Comment: @XCoder First of all you can create jar with all dependencies included with maven assembly plugin. And then use it for production. The second option is to have a repository, accessible from all dev/qa/prod boxes.

Comment: @madhead thanks though I've already mentioned the first solution in my question. But what if the building of that jar ain't in my hand. Also, seems like what I want ain't possible [See My Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14118593/566092). So if you can create an answer with the options you mentioned, I'll be glad to accept.

Comment: But why do you need to use the `system` scope? Why not let Maven take care of things and have a simple dependency jar that will be added to the classpath by Maven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had gone through the link provided by @Sean and it seems like what I want is not possible.

Shall I vote to delete this question ?

Although the answer is IT CAN'T BE DONE and heres' why :

`Project-A -> Project-B`

The diagram above says that Project-A depends on Project-B. When A declares B as an optional dependency in its POM, this relationship remains unchanged. Its just like a normal build where Project-B will be added in its classpath.

`Project-X -> Project-A`

But when another project(Project-X) declares Project-A as a dependency in its POM, the optional dependency takes effect. You'll notice that Project-B is not included in the classpath of Project-X; `you will need to declare it directly in your POM in order for B to be included in X's classpath.`

Taken from  [Official Documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)

Answer (score 2):

The [`system` scope](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies) is not supposed to be used for actual jar dependencies that will be packaged with another application. Quoting from the official documentation:

> Dependencies with the scope system are always available and are not looked up in repository. They are usually used to tell Maven about dependencies which are provided by the JDK or the VM. Thus, system dependencies are especially useful for resolving dependencies on artifacts which are now provided by the JDK, but where available as separate downloads earlier. Typical example are the JDBC standard extensions or the Java Authentication and Authorization Service (JAAS).

You should use the default `compile` scope.

Comment: Seems like you misunderstood my question, I've edited it to explain in more detail.

Comment: Hm, I don't see the difference. You said "Now I write another application in which I added X.jar as a **system dependency**", doesn't that mean that you're using the `system` scope?

Comment: Maybe you should post the relevant sections showing how exactly you declare these dependencies.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but what I'm trying ain't possible - [Official Documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, use the (default) compile scope and add `<exclusions>` for transitive dependencies you don't want / need.

See:  [Maven > Optional Dependencies and Dependency Exclusions](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)

Answer (score 0):

So, your `X` module is mavenized? Then you can install it locally with `mvn clean install` and then use it in another projects with all transitive dependencies and `compile` scope. This case is good till you do everything on you own machine. As far as you want to share the code with others or configure CI build you need `X` with its pom available to others. The best way to do this is to have your own artifactory, accessible from all other machines. You install `X` there and use it with `compile` scope as ususal, just need to add new repo to pom.

Comment: yes X is a maven project. But seems like I'm still unable to explain my issue. Although I can see it isn't possible so I just got the POM used in the project A, and have included it in my project X so that project X can have project B as a dependency.